# Unit of $\mathbb Q(\zeta_7)$ of infinite order

Tags: ring-theory, cyclotomic-fields

What is a unit of $\mathbb Q(\zeta_7)$ of infinite order?

I understand from the [definition of a unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_(ring_theory)) that I'm trying to find a number with unlimited powers of $\zeta_7$ whose product with another number is $1$. However, while I can find ways to make $\pm 1$ on a finite scale (eg. $\zeta_7^6*\zeta_7$, $1+\zeta_7^4 * 1+\zeta_7+\zeta_7^2$, $\zeta_7^{15}*\zeta_7^{20}$) and then add appropriate amounts of them in a series (eg. $\zeta_7^2 *\sum_{n=1}^m(-1)^n*\zeta_7^{7n+5}$ for even $m$), the only way I can seem to come up with that on an infinite scale is something like [Grandi's series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grandi%27s_series) (letting $m$ in the previous example go to infinity). That doesn't seem like a valid response.

Can someone poke me along in the right direction?

Comment: The first paragraph of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclotomic_unit seems relevant.

Comment: @RaviFernando Are you pointing out the line "the numbers $(\zeta^a_n − 1)/(\zeta_n − 1)$ for $(a, n) = 1$, and $\pm \zeta^a_n$ generate the group of cyclotomic units in this case ($n$ power of a prime)"? So how would I make one of infinite order? Multiply them all: $\prod_{7 \nmid k}^\infty (\zeta^k_7 − 1)/(\zeta_7 − 1)$?

Comment: I don't think that infinite product would converge.  But you don't need to take an infinite product, in any case, just picking one of the units $(\zeta_7^k - 1)/(\zeta_7 - 1)$ for $7 \nmid k$ should suffice.  Having infinite order isn't a very strong condition:  in fact, the only elements in $\mathbb Q(\zeta_7)^{\times}$ with finite order are the 14th roots of unity, $\pm \zeta_7^k$.  In particular, if you can prove that a unit doesn't lie on the unit circle in $\mathbb C$, then it must have infinite order.

Comment: Also, I just realized I may not have answered all of your questions.  Technically speaking, a unit of $\mathbb Q(\zeta_7)$ just means anything with a multiplicative inverse, namely anything nonzero because $\mathbb Q(\zeta_7)$ is a field.  But since that question isn't very interesting, you're probably looking for a unit in the ring of integers, namely an element of $\mathbb Z[\zeta_7]$ that has a multiplicative inverse in $\mathbb Z[\zeta_7]$.  The units mentioned above have this property.

Comment: And "infinite order" means infinite order as an element of the multiplicative group of units $\mathbb Q(\zeta_7)^{\times}$; that is, there is no finite number $n \neq 0$ with $u^n = 1$.  If the complex absolute value of $u$ is not 1, then this is automatically true, because $|u^n| = |u|^n \neq 1$.

Comment: I should mention, by the way, that it's worth checking why $(\zeta_7^k - 1)/(\zeta_7 - 1)$ and its reciprocal are both actually in $\mathbb Z[\zeta_7]$.  This is a nice exercise on its own, and justifies why those particular numbers are used.